# Why does this image controlled by HTML and CSS automatically rotate?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is controlled by the following CSS code:

```
img.background
{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The following HTML code also controls the image:

```
<img class = "background" src = "images/bhleerotated.JPG">
```

Even when this image is rotated 180 degrees, it still shows up as an image with the same orientation as the image that is not rotated. Why does this occur?

Comment: Sounds like caching or you're linking to the wrong image.

Comment: Maybe it's an animated JPG. If you provide a link to the image in question, we could check. Other than that, like @BoltClock suggested, it may have something to do with caching _or_ there could be other code in the CSS that controls the image. Or there might me a JavaScript function somewhere that rotates it.

Comment: Some image viewers rotate images for you when you view them but don't actually save the correct rotation. Perhaps this is what's happening here?

Comment: Agree with @NilsKaspersson. Try rotating the image in some image program and then saving the rotated copy properly.

Comment: @Aneesh That is what I did. It still shows up in the same orientation as if I didn't rotate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with the code you provided and CSS Transform: rotate(45deg).  How are you rotating the image, Javascript/jQuery or CSS3 Transform?

JSFiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/eDGhR/

HTML:

```
<img class="background" src="images/bhleerotated.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
img.background {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute:
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/eDGhR/